# R: Unexpected output when using str_sub

Tags: r, char

I've got a vector of names in the "Last, First" format. I'm trying to use `str_sub` to create two new vectors with separated first and last names. Here is my code:

```
name <- c("Smith, Bob","Blow, Joe")
df <- data.frame(name)

df$n1 <- str_sub(df$name, start=str_locate(df$name, pattern = " ")+1,
             end=str_length(df$name))
df$n2 <- str_sub(df$name, end = str_locate(df$name, pattern = ",")-1)
```

However, I'm only getting the first letter of the first name and an error when trying to produce the last name (R is creating double the number of rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
cbind(df, do.call(rbind, strsplit(name, ', ')))

#        name     1   2
#1 Smith, Bob Smith Bob
#2  Blow, Joe  Blow Joe
```

Comment: I modified this to generate the new columns back into the data frame. Marking this solution as the answer as it doesn't require any additional packages. Thanks!

Comment: That's a bit strange because you used `stringr` in your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

data_frame(name = c("Smith, Bob","Blow, Joe") ) %>%
  separate(name, c("last_name", "first_name"), sep = ", ")
```

Edit: magrittr %>% syntax is just a fancy trick for chaining, and not strictly necessary. Here is a slightly simplified version.

```
original = data_frame(name = c("Smith, Bob","Blow, Joe") )
final = separate(original, name, c("last_name", "first_name"), sep = ", ")
```

separate, from the tidyr package, separates the name column from the original dataframe into two columns, last_name and first_name, splitting where it sees ", "

Comment: This looks really awesome, but I can't tell. Can you provide some description to help us understand your code? Thanks!